# ¿Errores de deployment aun teniendo todo bien configurado usando heroku y node?

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, github, heroku

Estoy intentando hacer deployment de una app que hice a forma de ejercicio de un curso en react. Se usa el Stack MERN y el codigo de mi index.js de parte del servidor es este

```
const express = require("express");
const conectarDB = require("./config/db");
const cors = require("cors");

//creando el servidor

const app = express();

//Conectar a la base de datos
conectarDB();

//Habilitar cors
app.use(cors());

//Habilitar express.json
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));
//Puerto de la app
const port = process.env.port || 4000;

//Importar rutas
app.use("/api/usuarios", require("./routes/usuarios"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/api/proyectos", require("./routes/proyectos"));
app.use("/api/tareas", require("./routes/tareas"));
//modify
//Arrancar app
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`El servidor esta funcionando en el puerto ${port}`);
});
```

en heroku me da el problema de :

```
2020-08-16T22:34:47.222788+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

y apaga el servidor. De ante mano gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Al parecer el [puerto no esta debidamente configurado](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#incorrect-port-setup) para el deploy en Heroku. Estas usando la environment variable `port` en vez de `PORT`. Prueba así:

```
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;
```

Guarda los cambios, y realiza otro deploy.